# Don't plot graph on null value on ngx-charts-line-chart

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap, ngx-charts

I, am using ngx-charts-line-chart to plot the graph. Getting an error on Null value  and the graph is ploted as 0 on the null value.

```
<ngx-charts-line-chart [results]="progressPerformance"
                           [scheme]="colorScheme"
                           [xAxis]="true"
                           [yAxis]="true"
                           [legend]="false"
                           [showGridLines]="false"
                           [showYAxisLabel]="true"
                           [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
                           [curve]="curve">
    </ngx-charts-line-chart>
```

**Errors**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLocaleString' of null
    at CircleSeriesComponent../src/common/circle-series.component.ts.CircleSeriesComponent.getTooltipText (index.js:8258)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (CircleSeriesComponent.html:37)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11922)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11315)
    at callViewAction (core.js:11556)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:11519)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11316)
    at callViewAction (core.js:11556)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:11498)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11321)
```

I don't want to plot the line on null value. How can I achieved this.

Here is the screen shot of my graph plot when the API value in null as well.

[image: screen shot]

As per the graph the 18 Feb has value null. The graph should not be plot. on that day and when i hover on that day getting the above errors.

API response[image: api data]

Reference issue found on the github - https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/issues/799. Saying need to add **makeNullPointInvisible with a default value of False** but don't know where to add

Comment: Can't you exclude the value from the list - filter the data before setting it on the component?

Comment: is their no alternate solutions ??